# Loading .pem onto puttygen error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, putty, pem

I'm trying to setup my AWS for an ubuntu VM. For this with putty, I'm using puttygen to get .ppk file from .pem (from AWS) and then I got an error message as shown below.

[image]

The environment is Windows 10. I actually tried this process on another Windows device and everything worked fine but not on mine. I assume that my laptop has some trouble with recognizing .pem file. Anyone has any better idea?

Thanks

Comment: Share what you have done till now, what tutorials/steps have you followed? Longterm solution is to use [linux bash on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/), which means you can ssh directly

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) + When re-posting there, explain where do you load the .pem from. Where did you store it? Show more screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

PuTTYgen, Release 0.73, Build platform: 64-bit x86 Windows
.Per file need to:
1. Encoding should be UTF-8 (not UTF-8 BOM or something else)
2. Check end of file symbols, need to be Windows CR LF
3. After "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" need to have an empty line